# Vimrc, two functionalities become one

Tags: vimrc

I have a vimrc file. In that file i have the following two lines.

```
noremap gg :silent exec "!/home/john/gf.sh /home/john/guides/"<enter><C-L>

nmap gh tlet @"=system('perl /home/john/get_buffer.pl')<enter>P<enter>^
```

The first command runs script *gf.sh*. Which, long story short, prints a file selected by the user, into /tmp/file.

The second command, *gh*. Prints /tmp/file, into buffer @". And then prints that buffer, wherever I happen to be in Vim.

What I am trying to achieve, is to execute both of those things with a single command. I just don't understand how to achieve that. I have been trying for well over an hour.

How can I, achieve those two functionalities, at once?

Comment: Is the `nmap` on `gh` relevant? The `tlet ` sequence looks a bit odd, so I can't tell if it's another mapping or just some keystrokes you want to have. As for combining, might be easier to use a function.

Comment: well, now i type gg, run that script where i tell which file should be catted into /tmp/file. Then I have to make the rest happen, somehow. So by typing "gh" in normal mode, I run the buffer perl script and paste its output automatically.

Comment: Are you looking for `:help :bar`? It sounds like you wish to run two commands, one immediately after the other

Comment: Yes i want to run two commands, one after the other. But as you can see, the latter one needs to return its output into the buffer.

Comment: Ideally your `.sh` script would print out content to STDIN then you just do `:put=systemlist('script.sh')`. Other you just need to run your commands one after another, e.g. `script.sh; cat /tmp/foo`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments the OP wishes to execute multiple commands in succession. In particular, the commands `silent exec ...` followed by `let @"= ...`. As D Ben Knoble suggests, this is a typical use case of a **function**.

```
function Foo()
  silent exec "!/home/john/gf.sh /home/john/guides/"
  redraw!
  let @"=system('perl /home/john/get_buffer.pl')
  normal! Pj^
endfunction
```

Then, one can call this function with a mapping

```
nnoremap gg :call Foo()<CR>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I need to read up on some vimscript.

Comment: Glad to be of help! I should have mentioned that `:normal xxx` acts as though `xxx` was pressed in normal mode by the user. `:help :normal` will provide more details.

Comment: no wait, the function gets implemented, every time i run vim. i put that function in my vimrc file.

Comment: Yes, place both the function and mapping in your vimrc.... or am I missing something?

Comment: I changed the function name, into something that starts in a lowercase. Which caused an error. But its corrected now.

Comment: Oh yes, that trips me up too. Glad it's working now :)